# Transfer table from vertical to horizontal in sql

Tags: sql, data-transform

I want to transfer table from

[image]

to what looks like this:

[image]

Not sure how to approach?

Code I had is this

```
FROM TABLE A, 
(SELECT PART_NO, SUM(QUANTITY) AS Type_1
FROM TABLE
WHERE STYPE = 'Type_1'
GROUP BY PART_NO, STYPE) B, 
(SELECT PART_NO, SUM(QUANTITY) AS Type_2
FROM TABLE
WHERE STYPE = 'Type_2'
GROUP BY PART_NO, STYPE) C,
(SELECT PART_NO, SUM(QUANTITY) AS Type_3
FROM TABLE
WHERE STYPE = 'Type_3'
GROUP BY PART_NO, STYPE) D,
(SELECT PART_NO, SUM(QUANTITY) AS Type_4
FROM TABLE
WHERE STYPE = 'Type_4'
GROUP BY PART_NO, STYPE) E
WHERE A.PART_NO = B.PART_NO
AND A.PART_NO = C.PART_NO
AND A.PART_NO = D.PART_NO
AND A.PART_NO = E.PART_NO
AND A.PART_NO = F.PART_NO
GROUP BY A.PART_NO, B.Type_1, C.Type_2, D.Type_2, E.Type_4
```

But it removes the rows with nan. Not sure where did i do wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is a type of pivoting that you can produce using conditional aggregation.

For example, you can do:

```
select
  part_no,
  sum(case when stype = 'Type 1' then quantity end) as type_1,
  sum(case when stype = 'Type 2' then quantity end) as type_2,
  sum(case when stype = 'Type 3' then quantity end) as type_3
from my_table
group by part_no
```